# ESLint rule to prefer import from index.js when available?

Tags: javascript, eslint

If I export a module through index.js, I now have two ways I can import that module.  Is there a way to have ESLint enforce that the import through index.js should be used instead of directly importing the module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is [`no-internal-modules`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-internal-modules.md).